# Containers Not Aligned Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am working on a website that has a left and right container, which you can see if you run the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <style>
    
    .card
    {
        background-color: #EFF3FC!important;
    }
    
    html, body
    {
        height: 100%;
    }
    
    .toggleBlue
    {
        color: blue;
    }
    
    .regular
    {
        color: gray;
    }
    
    #radioDiv 
    {
        text-align: left;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    .required:before
    {
        content: "*";
        color: red;
    }
     .btnBlue
    {
        background: #1467ba;
        height: 25px;
        width: 70px;
        font-size: 14px; 
        color: white;   
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .btnSave
    {
        background: #1467ba;
        height: 25px;
        width: 70px;
        font-size: 14px; 
        color: white;   
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

       
    </style>
    
    <body>
        
        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        
            <div class="row no-gutters h-100">
            
            
                <div class="col-md-2 my-auto p-1">
                
                
                    <div class="card card-block pl-2 ">
                         
                         <br>
                    
                        <img class="mx-auto" src="CoreCLM_Logo.JPG" alt="CoreCLM Logo" width="80px" height="50px"> </img>

                    
                        <hr class="mx-auto" style="height:1px;border:none;color:#333;background-color:#333;width:80%;" />
                    
                        <p class="toggleBlue"> 1. Procurement Requests & Funding </p>
                        
                        <p class="regular"> 2. Suppiles or Services </p>
                        
                        <p class="regular"> 3. Contract Type </p>
                        
                        <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>  <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
                        
                        
 
                    </div>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-md-10 my-auto">
                
                    <div class="card card-block">
                    
                        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: #E6E6E6;">
                        
                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button> 
                            
                                
                            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                  <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Home </a>
                                  </li> 
                                  <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Edit Profile </a>
                                  </li> 
                                  <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Logout </a>
                                  </li> 
                                </ul>
                                <form>
                                
                                <button class="btnSave"  type="submit"> SAVE </button>
                                <button class="btnBlue"  type="submit"> CANCEL </button>
                                
                                </form>
                                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 text-center">
                                  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                                  <input type="image" src="searchicon.jpg" width="38px" height="38px"/>
                                </form>
                              </div>
                        </nav>
                        
                        <div class="p-3">
                        
                        <form>
                        
                            <p style="font-size: 18px; text-align: center;"> Ensure the accuracy and completeness of procurement request packages and availability of funds to fulfill the procurement request </p>
                            
                            <br>
                            <p style="font-size: 16px; color: gray;"> Have you advised customers on the completeness and accuracy of the procurement request? </p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div id="radioDiv">
                                    <input type="radio" id="yes1" name="option">
                                    <label for="yes">  Yes  </label> 
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="radio" id="no1" name="option">
                                    <label for="no"> No </label>           
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                            <p class="required" style="font-size: 16px; color: gray;">Has the funding type been identified? </p>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div id="radioDiv">
                                    <input type="radio" id="yes2" name="option">
                                    <label for="yes">  Yes  </label> 
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="radio" id="no2" name="option">
                                    <label for="no"> No  </label>           
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        
                        </form>
                        
                             <form class="form-inline">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label style="color: gray; font-size: 16px;" class="required" for="fundingAmount">If yes, then what is the funding amount? </label>
                                <input type="number" id="fundingAmount" class="form-control mx-sm-3">
                              </div>
                        </form>
                            

                        <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 
                        
                    
                     </div>
                     
                 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style="background-color: white">
                        
                          <div class="col-md-10">
                              <div style="color: gray; font-size: 14px;" class="required">Required Question </div>
                          </div>
                          
                          <div class="col-md-2">
                              
                              <button class="btnBlue" type="submit"> > </button>
                          </div>
                    </nav>
                
                </div>
                               

            </div>
        
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I am confused why the right and left container are not perfectly the same in terms of their height. I have tried adding br tags to adjust the height, but it always overshoots or undershoots it. How should I fix this?

Comment: It seems that your last edit accidentally removed a lot of information and replaced it by gibberish. I undid that.

Comment: You have again removed the code which you are referring to with "if you run the following HTML code:". I am starting to think you do that on purpose. But since you are referring to the code which you have removed I will assume that it was another, extremely weird accident and add it again. If I am wrong and you intentionally remove that vital information please provide an explanation. Note that intentional vandalising of your post is inappropriate and will always be undone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're using BS 4.3 but upgrade to BS 4.6 and utilize Bootstrap Flex utilities and add the .align-items-stretch class to the parent of your left and right containers. You have to declare that you're using flex with d-flex. Set the cols with .w-25 and .w-75, which sets up your sidebar and main structure...play with the alignment classes, you'll see what's going on. Do not set fixed heights, I'd get rid of your padding and margin classes, all that eats up space and messes with your overall layout and structure. Add padding and margin once your know your house is built right. Get rid of all the break tags too. But this should put you on track to solve your height stretching dilema.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-stretch">
        <div class="w-25 bg-info">
            <div class="bg-info">
                <img class="mx-auto" src="CoreCLM_Logo.JPG" alt="CoreCLM Logo" height="50px">
                <p class="toggleBlue"> 1. Procurement Requests &amp; Funding </p>
                <p class="regular"> 2. Suppiles or Services </p>
                <p class="regular"> 3. Contract Type </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="w-75 bg-warning">
            Content stretches here...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```